# Is there any way to use single BS Modal and a single JS code for Multiple Delete/ Confirm Operation?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a PHP Project, In this Project, there are multiple delete operation Like "Delete Chef", "Delete Customer", "Delete Restaurant", "Delete Feedback".
For This Purpose, I am using 18 Modals and 18 JS Codes.
I want to know is there any way to use single Modal and a Single JS Code for All These Operation ?
My Code is:

**1) Delete Button:**

```
<a rel="<?php echo $chef_id; ?>" data-page=<?php echo $page; ?> 
href="javascript:void(0)" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs- 
placement="top" title="Delete" class="dropdown-item small1 text-danger 
del_appr_chef_link"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-sm"></i> Delete</a>
```

**2) BS Modal:**

```
<div class="modal bounceIn" id="del_appr_chef" data-bs-backdrop="static" 
data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria- 
labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4 class="modal-header modal-title bg-dark text-white py-2">Delete Chef ?
        </h4>
        <div class="modal-body text-dark">
            <h5>You Want to Delete Chef ?</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center py-1">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm del_appr_chef">Delete</a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" data-bs- 
         dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**3) JavaScript Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".del_appr_chef_link").on('click', function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("rel");
        var page = $(this).data("page");
        var del_url = "all_chefs.php?del=" + id + "&page=" + page + " ";
        $(".del_appr_chef").attr("href", del_url);
        $("#del_appr_chef").modal('show');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bind to the document instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', ".del_appr_chef_link", function(el) {
        let that = el.target;
        var id = $(that).attr("rel");
        var page = $(that).data("page");
        var del_url = "all_chefs.php?del=" + id + "&page=" + page + " ";
        $(".del_appr_chef").attr("href", del_url);
        $("#del_appr_chef").modal('show');
    });
});
```